# SQL: Error at column IN @parameter after using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server

As the title says, I am running into the following SQL error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'

The place I have the IN keyword used is

```
AND (CASE WHEN (@client IS NOT NULL)
        THEN ([Client] IN @client)
     END)
```

And `@client` is declared as it follows:

```
declare @client varchar(50)
```

However, I tried replacing @client with `('Text', 'Text', 'Text')` and it still did not work.

I searched on the internet for a bit and couldn't find the exact reason why I am getting this.

Also, the `@client` parameter will be set in a C# program to be a list of strings.

Thanks.

Comment: That statement makes no sense, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code attempt is product specific.)

Comment: I have more conditions in a WHERE clause (more ANDs) and this is one of them, and I want to do it to also check if the [Client] values are in client if the client param is not null

Comment: @jarlh using MS SQL

Comment: You cannot pass and consume list of values like this. Either you have to define your own table type in sql server or you have to pass comma separated string values and have to use `string_split` function

Comment: @PawanNogariya I did try to use comma separated string values and it still did not work :/

Comment: Did you use string_split function after that?

Comment: @PawanNogariya yes, same error.

Comment: Bit more information would help: Like @client value-- Is it the comma-separated string or user-defined table which contains the list of string?

Comment: Comma separated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you are passing comma separated values single string like this from C#

```
"Text,Text,Text"
```

and taking it into your `@client` variable, 
so basically your `@client` will be set to that string

`@client='Text,Text,Text'`

you can do something like this

```
AND (@client IS NULL
        OR [Client] IN (select value from string_split(@client,',')))
```

Comment: Yup, this was it. Thanks a lot!